# USB C to C receptacles with a multiplexer in between

Tags: usb, usb-c

I'm doing a board that has two USB C receptacles.  After the first receptacle is a multiplexer which can route the USB signals either to the second USB receptacle or another connector.

The first USB C receptacle is upstream facing and intended to plug into the host PC.  The other USB C receptacle is downstream facing and is intended to be the "host" to the downstream device, using a cable with USB C plugs on both ends.

Once this is running, the downstream device should be unaware that its signals are going through a multiplexer.

For the USB2.0 signals DP and DM, it's clear that I just need to route those straight across.  However For the USB3.0 signals TX/RX pairs, I'm not sure if I need to swap the TX and RX on the downstream facing receptacle, partly because I'm not sure whether TX and RX refer to the host as the owner of direction, and I'm not sure how standard USB cables are made.

So the question is: Do I need to swap the TX/RX on the downstream facing receptacle?  Can someone point me to a schematic where someone has done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to know is hat USB C cables contain 4 pairs of high speed signals, (TX1, TX2, RX1, RX2) and only 2 pair is used for USB 3.0. You either need to use TX1 and RX1, or TX2 and RX2.

Just connecting the signals to the other outlet does not work, you don't know if both  sides have the cable in the same orientation.

This requires you to do cable orientation on both USB C plugs and switch your mux to the proper pairs

According to [table 3-10 in the USB C spec](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf):

| USB Type-C Plug #1 |  | Wire |  | USB Type-C Plug #2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pin Signal | Signal Name | Wire number | Signal name | Pin Signal | Signal Name |
| A1, B1, A12, B12 | GND | 1 [16] | GND_PWRrt1 [GND_PWRrt2] | A1, B1, A12, B12 | GND |
| A4, B4, A9, B9 | VBUS | 2 [17] | PWR_VBUS1 [PWR_VB US2] | A4, B4, A9, B9 | VBUS |
| A5 | CC | 3 | CC | A5 | CC |
| B5 | VCONN | 18 | PWR_VCONN (See Section 4.9) | B5 | VCONN |
| A6 | Dp1 | 4 | UTP_Dp | A6 | Dp1 |
| A7 | Dn1 | 5 | UTP_Dn | A7 | Dn1 |
| A2 | TXp1 | 6 | SDPp1 | B11 | RXp1 |
| A3 | TXn1 | 7 | SDPn1 | B10 | RXn1 |
| B11 | RXp1 | 8 | SDPp2 | A2 | TXp1 |
| B10 | RXn1 | 9 | SDPn2 | A3 | TXn1 |
| B2 | TXp2 | 10 | SDPp3 | A11 | RXp2 |
| B3 | TXn2 | 11 | SDPn3 | A10 | RXn2 |
| A11 | RXp2 | 12 | SDPp4 | B2 | TXp2 |
| A10 | RXn2 | 13 | SDPn4 | B3 | TXn2 |
| A8 | SBU1 | 14 | SBU_A | B8 | SBU2 |

This shows that the cable swaps the signals around, every side transmits on the A2,A3,B2,B3 pins, and receives data on the A10,A11,B10,B11

You would need to take the data in from pins A10,A11,B10,B11, feed to though a mux, then another mux for the other port and then send it out on A2,A3,B2,B3 for both directions.

Depending on your exact muxes, you might need a active repeater in between to make sure the signals stay outside the eye

Comment: So the new mux you're talking about isn't to determine whether to route the incoming ("left") TX to the outgoing ("right") TX or RX.  The new mux you're talking about is whether to route the incoming TX to the outgoing TX on the A side, or the outgoing TX on the B side, right?  This decision being based on the detection of "right" plug orientation?  Couldn't I just always route left A10/A11 to right A2/A3, and left B10/B11 to right B2/B3?

Comment: You use the muxes to see if you have to receive from receive pair 1 or 2, and use it to see if you to transmit on pair 1 or 2. If you just route the wires though your device only works in 1 cable orientation. If you connect all the pairs together the reflections of the signal make the signal to noise ratio too low for proper communications

Comment: I've looked at a $5 passive USB-C-to-C coupler.  The two connectors are swapped in orientation so A and B are on one side, and B and A are on the other; the superspeed lines in that case go straight across and other swapping happens with the other wires.  I'm basing my design on that.  My board *is* a coupler with an option to divert all the signals elsewhere.  I have to use power from elsewhere on the PCB to run the mux, because VBUS doesn't come on until power is negotiated, which happens with CC lines, which is driven by the selected target, so there's a catch-22.

Comment: @Sonicsmooth with a passive coupler, it may work or not work depending on the orientation of the cables at either side. The noise introduced to the high speed lines affects the some devices making them not work. The extra impedance to the power path causes some devices to mall function. Another dangerous thing that can happen if you mix 5A cables with 3A, the charger sees the first 5A cable, so it offers a 5A charge profile, but the 3A cable is not designed for 5A. If any of the cables is using active vcon powered electronics for it's USB 3 boosters, it is unreliable

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Sonicsmooth How are the connectors swapped on the coupler, A1 pins to B12 etc or A1 pins to B1?

Comment: A1 to B12, B1 to A12